# "diff orig new" vs. "diff new orig"

Tags: cat, diff, arguments

When comparing 2 files using `diff`, the `original` file is provided as first argument, and the `new` (modified) as second argument.

```
diff original new
```

Presumably, the logic behind this ordering was to show how to transform the original into the new one, using left-to-right convention for the flow of time.

I am having problems with this logic. When I am diffing two files, I intuitively use the inverse notation:

```
diff new original
```

so that I can, after reviewing the changes, cat the new file into the old one, and thus "patch" it to the new version.

```
cat new > original
```

But using "my" inverted notation is confusing, because diff shows `+` for deletion, and `-` for addition.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: FWIW I also find `diff` reads backwards but I've not really found a useful solution. I suppose I could trivially create my own variant `diffr` but I've never quite got round to it.

Comment: Your argument order doesn't make sense to me, but if to implement it I would also do some trivial script or alias.  Apart from that, "cp" would probably be more intuitive than "cat" to copy files afterwards.

Comment: @GöranUddeborg, `cp new original` is still the reverse order to the `diff` command.  I would suggest just using `cat >original <new` if you want something where the sequence matches.  And double check your commands before you run them.  ;)

Comment: You know, people had this argument in 1970's, when they were trying to decide if assignment in assembly languages should be written as `MOV src,dest` or `MOV dest,src`.  There is still no universally accepted convention to this day.  Other debates you might also consider investigating: vi vs. emacs, tabs vs. spaces.

Comment: *How can I resolve this problem?* Which problem? That you are using a tool contrary to how it was designed to work? That the result doesn't match what you want? or That you are getting confused?. Possible solutions: (1)develop a new tool. (2) use sed/awk/tr to change the `+` to `-` and viceversa. (3) Change the way you read the output to understand it the opposite way (4) make a function that takes the arguments to cat the other way around, like `mycat(){ cp "$2" "$1"; }` or (In MY opinion:) (5) Use the tool as it was designed to work and get used to it. Or even (6) make a function for diff.

Answer (score 3):

A quick look at the man page suggests you can use the `--from-file=original` and `--to-file=new` options, if you want to be explicit. You'll be typing a little more, but will give you the flexibility you need and as a bonus make things explicit.

```
diff --to-file=new --from-file=original
```

If you want, you can also write a simple wrapper script this that takes only the file names in the order you want and runs this for you.

EDIT: This is for GNU diff...not sure if this are standard (POSIX) options though.

Comment: `--from-file=FILE1` Compare `FILE1` to each operand; `FILE1` may be a directory. 
`--to-file=FILE1` Compare each operand to `FILE1`; `FILE1` may be a directory.
[Source](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/diffutils.git/tree/doc/diffutils.texi#n3816). Specifying both doesn't make any sense and results in an error message for me.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple solution!

Write the following script:

```
if [ "$#" -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "USAGE: diff2 newfile oldfile"
    exit 1;
fi

diff $2 $1
```

Save it on one of the folders on PATH (maybe `/bin` or `/usr/bin`) as diff2.

And that's it, you can now call:

`diff2 newfile oldfile`, which will then call `diff oldfile newfile`